# Trimble Access vs. TerraFlex: Which is simpler for creating data entry forms?

Tags: gps, trimble, data-collection

I am working on an archaeological project and need to create forms for users in the field to use and take photos. I am renting a Trimble GNSS unit and can get Trimble Access for free with the unit, or I can pay for Terraflex separately. Terraflex seems simpler to use, but I want to keep costs low.

Does anyone have experience with both Trimble Access and TerraFlex? How hard is it to create forms with Trimble Access compared to TerraFlex? I have created a TerraFlex trial account and successfully tested creating forms and tasks on the office/web side which can be pushed out to mobile users.

Comment: I think this is too broad because you are effectively asking for a list of requirements for two products to be compared. For focused Q&A I recommend you take the requirement of most concern to you and, if you think one or other product may not be able to meet it, then ask about that specifically.

Comment: I edited this a bit to focus more on what seemed like the real question (ease of creating forms), feel free to roll back those changes or make your own.